# Retrofit 2, parameters transformation

Tags: java, retrofit2

Good afternoon! This is request's URL to *Google Maps* service:

```
base_url/geocode/json?latlng=10.00,10.00&key=my_api_key
```

Note that this request contains parameter `latlng`, which composed of two `double`, separated by comma.

I want to write more compact and laconic code, when make request, like in this code sample:

```
mMapsGeocodeApi.getAddressByLocation(
                location.getLat(),
                location.getLng(),
                API_KEY);
```

However, parameter `latLng` - is not two double variables and I can't write code, which takes two variables. I have to transform and combine `double`s to `String`, before give variables to request method. But this is looks like very bad...

At this time, method written in interface, like in this code illustration:

```
 @GET("geocode/json")
 void getAddressByLocation(@Query("latlng") String latLng, 
                           @Query("key") String key);
```

---

How I can create method, which take two `double` variables, transform they to `String` (inside this method) and than execute request with parameter `latlng`. In addition, how I can make this in request's class (instead current interface) `MapsGeocodeApi`, which uses Retrofit?

P.S. I know, how make this with third-party methods, but I want know how it make in class, which takes `Retrofit` for making requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just pass it as a single object with a string converter applied to perform serialization in `$lat,$lng` format?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv, how? You about `String.format(...`?

Comment: No. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep your service to domain model as much as possible. If you have to transform its representation, -- don't use the representation directly in the service because it's a responsibility of the transport layer. What if, for example, you decide to switch from Retrofit someday or use another service that does not deal with strings? Anyway, let's supposed you have the following latitude/longitude domain object (at least it has to be something like this):

```java
final class LatLng {

    final double latitude;
    final double longitude;

    LatLng(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

And your service is something like this:

```java
interface IGeoService {

    @GET("geocode/json")
    Call<Void> getAddressByLocation(@Query("latlng") LatLng latLng, @Query("key") String key);

}
```

```java
private static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(... your service URL here ...)
        .addConverterFactory(new Converter.Factory() {
            @Override
            public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
                // Is it LanLng from the above?
                if ( !type.equals(LatLng.class) ) {
                    // No, let Retrofit manage this itself
                    return super.stringConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
                }
                // We can convert it ourselves by creating a custom converter from LatLng to String
                // (No worries about + -- javac should be smart enough to use StringBuilder here)
                return (Converter<LatLng, String>) latLng -> latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude;
            }
        })
        .addConverterFactory(... your basic message converter here ...)
        .build();
```

```java
final IGeoService geoService = retrofit.create(IGeoService.class);
geoService.getAddressByLocation(new LatLng(10, 10), "key").execute();
```

Something like that. Traced URL (if intercepted in `OkHttpClient`) output:

> http://whatever/geocode/json?latlng=10.0,10.0&key=key

By the way, you can remove the `key` parameter from the interface since the `key` parameter can be added dynamically in an interceptor.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need! But can be domain layer somewhere in another place? How you told: I can change Retofit to another library and all my convert factories will be useless.

Comment: @RostislavDugin I meant that you should not pass strings directly because they are just _representations_ for a particular object. Retrofit allows to separate _your domain objects_ like `LatLng` and _the service API representation_ like raw strings by using a string converter.

Comment: @RostislavDugin Having this in mind, just imagine the following scenario: you use strings in the interface, you use `String.format` (directly on indirectly -- does not really matter)... And everything is fine until someone tells you to switch from your current web service to another one that accepts locations in totally different format. Then you'd have to fix **every** code piece for the whole bunch of such interaction smeared over all of your application. Simply speaking, your domain/service layer should not know about a particular web service specifics.

Comment: But what if I have two methods, which takes one object, but it must be converted particular for each method? I should use annotations?

Comment: @RostislavDugin Sorry, can you elaborate?

Comment: @RostislavDugin Ahh, you mean different representations for different service methods? Yes, your converter should analyze annotations to make proper transformations.

Comment: And small question: how insert API key by interceptor?

Comment: @RostislavDugin For example, like this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-add-query-parameters-to-every-request